# powershell Start-Service fails

Tags: powershell

I have very simple powershell script that starts service remotely.

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { Start-Service "My test service v1" }
```

works fine but

```
$myval="My test service v1"
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { Start-Service $myval }
```

fails with

> Cannot validate argument on parameter 'InputObject'. The argument is
>   null or empty. Supply an argument that is not null or empty and then
>   try the command again.
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Start-Service], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
>       + PSComputerName        : mdfiletest

To me they are the same. Why is this not working? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not work because when the scriptblock is executed on the remote server, the variable `$myval` does not exist in session state; it only exists on the local (client) side. The powershell v2/v3 compatible way to do this is:

```
invoke-command -session $session -scriptblock {
      param($val); start-service $val } -args $myval
```

Another powershell v3 (only) way is like this:

```
invoke-command -session $session -scriptblock { start-service $using:myval }
```

The `$using` prefix is a special pseudo-scope which will capture the local variable and try to serialize it and send it remotely. Strings are always serializable (remotable.)